# Order by slow query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

i am using this query to fetching products.the product table has 302,716 rows.it is taking too much time to execute around 2-3 minutes.but when i removed order by it takes less time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  product.ProductID,
  company.CompanyName 
FROM
  product 
  INNER JOIN company 
    ON company.CompanyID = product.CompanyID 
  LEFT JOIN company_csv_data 
    ON company.CompanyID = company_csv_data.CompanyID 
  LEFT JOIN productcategory 
    ON product.ProductID = productcategory.ProductID 
  LEFT JOIN category 
    ON category.CategoryID = productcategory.CategoryID 
  LEFT JOIN supplier 
    ON product.supplier = supplier.id 
  LEFT JOIN template_vouchers tm 
    ON product.ProductID = tm.voucher_id 
WHERE company.turn_on = 1 
  AND product.ProductEndDate >= CURRENT_DATE 
  AND turn_off = 1 
GROUP BY product.ProductID 
ORDER BY clicks DESC,
  product.CodeOpen DESC,
  product.Online,
  product.EntryDate DESC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: it is taking too much time to execute around 3 min.

Comment: Had you try indexing ?

Comment: You have no aggregating functions, so what does GROUP BY do? And @TheConstructor's right - you select no columns from your LEFT JOINed tables, so they serve no purpose.

Comment: How are your tables defined? What do you need any of these `LEFT JOIN`s for? (To me it seems no column of those tables appears in `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` O.o)

Comment: The time consumption does not only depend on the product table. The size (and structure, index, ...) of all other joined tables are having an effect too. Does the query perform significantly better without the ORDER BY?

Comment: @SebastianH : yes without order by it takes less time.

Comment: @Strawberry :i am using group by to fetch only distinct records because distinct is not working in this query

Comment: "DISTINCT is not working"? Eh? Perhaps you should consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Do not mix ASC and DESC in `ORDER` clause - it slows down sorting a lot. Make sure all columns you are sorting by have indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You could improve the query's speed/performance by creating indexes for the columns in the select and where clauses (this will slow down insert, delete and update statements..)

Comment: And breathing helps in staying alive. Who upvotes this?